# Почему истёк срок действия кода подтверждения Pyrogram

Tags: telegram, telebot, telethon, pyrogram

Делаю бота, позволяющего войти в аккаунт телеграм. Для бота служит PyTelegramApi, войти в аккаунт пытаюсь с помощью Pyrogram. Pyrogram каждый раз выдаёт ошибку the confirmation code has expired. Причём я пробовал использовать Telethon, ошибка та же самая.

```
Telegram says: [400 PHONE_CODE_EXPIRED] - The confirmation code has expired (caused by "auth.SignIn")
```

Comment: А юзер не в ЧС?

Answer (score 0):

попробуй запрашивать у пользователя код, скажем, через точки, тогда телеграм не будет считать его истекшим

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]